# How programatically set gravity_layout to NavigationView - Android

Tags: android, android-navigationview

In my app user can chose in what side he'll have NavigationView

how set layout_gravity="end" programatically ?

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFF"
    >


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/light_grey"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp">

    </ListView>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Do you want to open drawer from left or right?

Comment: Yeah, when app start it will ask user, from what side he want to open navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can play with this:

```
 DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            params.setLayoutDirection(Gravity.START);
        }
        navigationView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin

For this to work, the entire xml has to be a `DrawerLayout` (with id `drawer_layout`, containing a `NavigationView`)

`val params = drawer_layout.main_navigation_view.layoutParams as DrawerLayout.LayoutParams`

then to open from the left side

`params.gravity = Gravity.START`

or from the right side

`params.gravity = Gravity.END`

Answer (score 0):

Get your DrawerLayout variable declared and initialize in Activity and use following line to set its gravity :

```
drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Where drawer is variable of your DrawerLayout and you can set gravity according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[openDrawer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#closeDrawer(int))** method to open drawer programaticaly

> void openDrawer (int gravity)
>
> Open the specified drawer by animating it out of view.
>
> Parameters
> gravity     int: **Gravity.LEFT** to move the left drawer or Gravity.RIGHT for the right. **GravityCompat.START** or **GravityCompat.END** may also be used.

**sample code**

```
drawer.OpenDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
drawer.OpenDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
```